# scrapy none type object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, scrapy, nonetype

I am trying to extracting json data from a website by making a post request I am getting all the data problem is some of the json data fields are `None` e.g `{'tax_history': None}`
and I am aware of the fact that we can't iterate or subscript the none value. I'd like to skip the None values just and get remaining data from json. Unfortunately, I couldn't able to do that every time I run the crawler it just skips the whole link and outputs the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zerox/realtor/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 857, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(  # type: ignore[misc]
  File "/home/zerox/realtor/realtor-scrapy/rs2.py", line 75, in parse_details
    tax_building_assessment = [
  File "/home/zerox/realtor/realtor-scrapy/rs2.py", line 76, in <listcomp>
    tab["assessment"]["building"] for tab in prop_tax
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import csv
import json
from datetime import datetime


def parse_date(dt):
    dateobj = datetime.strptime(dt, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
    return dateobj.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")


# realtor scraper class
class RealtorScraper(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "realtor-scraper"

    custom_settings = {
        "FEED_FORMAT": "csv",
        "FEED_URI": "tax.csv",
        "LOG_FILE": "realtor.log",
        # "CONCURRENT_REQUESTS": 5,
    }

    base_url = "https://www.realtor.com/api/v1/hulk?client_id=rdc-x&schema=vesta"

    headers = {
        "authority": "www.realtor.com",
        "accept": "application/json",
        "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
        "cache-control": "max-age=0",
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "origin": "https://www.realtor.com",
        "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
        "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
        "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
        "sec-gpc": "1",
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.60 Safari/537.36",
    }

    json_data = {
        "query": "",
        "variables": {},
        "callfrom": "PDP",
        "isClient": True,
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        prop_id = []
        with open("items_realtor_property_3.csv", "r") as file:
            data = csv.DictReader(file)
            for col in data:
                prop_id.append(col["id"])

        for id in prop_id:
            print(id)
            self.json_data[
                "query"
            ] = f'{{\n    home(property_id: "{id}") {{\n      advertisers {{\n        team_name\n        address {{\n          city\n          country\n          line\n          postal_code\n          state\n          state_code\n        }}\n        builder {{\n          fulfillment_id\n        }}\n        broker {{\n          accent_color\n          designations\n          fulfillment_id\n          name\n          logo\n        }}\n        email\n        fulfillment_id\n        href\n        mls_set\n        name\n        nrds_id\n        office {{\n          address {{\n            city\n            coordinate {{\n              lat\n              lon\n            }}\n            country\n            line\n            postal_code\n            state\n            state_code\n          }}\n          application_url\n          email\n          lead_email {{\n            to\n            cc\n          }}\n          fulfillment_id\n          hours\n          href\n          mls_set\n          out_of_community\n          name\n          phones {{\n            ext\n            number\n            primary\n            trackable\n            type\n          }}\n          photo {{\n            href\n          }}\n          slogan\n        }}\n        phones {{\n          ext\n          number\n          primary\n          trackable\n          type\n        }}\n        photo {{\n          href\n        }}\n        slogan\n        type\n      }}\n      buyers {{\n        address {{\n          city\n          country\n          line\n          postal_code\n          state\n          state_code\n        }}\n        broker {{\n          accent_color\n          designations\n          fulfillment_id\n          name\n          logo\n        }}\n        email\n        fulfillment_id\n        href\n        mls_set\n        name\n        nrds_id\n        office {{\n          address {{\n            city\n            coordinate {{\n              lat\n              lon\n            }}\n            country\n            line\n            postal_code\n            state\n            state_code\n          }}\n          application_url\n          email\n          lead_email {{\n            to\n            cc\n          }}\n          fulfillment_id\n          hours\n          href\n          mls_set\n          out_of_community\n          name\n          phones {{\n            ext\n            number\n            primary\n            trackable\n            type\n          }}\n          photo {{\n            href\n          }}\n          slogan\n        }}\n        phones {{\n          ext\n          number\n          primary\n          trackable\n          type\n        }}\n        photo {{\n          href\n        }}\n        slogan\n        type\n      }}\n      community {{\n        permalink\n      }}\n      estimates {{\n        current_values(source: "corelogic")\n        @include_if(field: "status", operator: in, value: "sold,off_market,other") {{\n          estimate\n          estimate_high\n          estimate_low\n          date\n          source {{\n            type\n            name\n          }}\n        }}\n      }}\n      days_on_market\n      description {{\n        baths\n        baths_3qtr\n        baths_full\n        baths_full_calc\n        baths_half\n        baths_max\n        baths_min\n        baths_partial_calc\n        baths_total\n        beds\n        beds_max\n        beds_min\n        construction\n        cooling\n        exterior\n        fireplace\n        garage\n        garage_max\n        garage_min\n        garage_type\n        heating\n        logo {{\n          href\n        }}\n        lot_sqft\n        name\n        pool\n        roofing\n        rooms\n        sqft\n        sqft_max\n        sqft_min\n        stories\n        styles\n        sub_type\n        text\n        type\n        units\n        year_built\n        year_renovated\n        zoning\n      }}\n      details {{\n        category\n        parent_category\n        text\n      }}\n      flags {{\n        is_coming_soon\n        is_contingent\n        is_deal_available\n        is_for_rent\n        is_foreclosure\n        is_garage_present\n        is_new_construction\n        is_pending\n        is_price_excludes_land\n        is_senior_community\n        is_short_sale\n        is_subdivision\n      }}\n      href\n      last_sold_date\n      last_sold_price\n      list_date\n      list_price\n      listing_id\n      local {{\n        flood {{\n          firststreet_url\n          fsid\n          flood_factor_score\n          flood_factor_severity\n          environmental_risk\n          trend_direction\n          fema_zone\n          insurance_quotes{{\n            provider_url\n            provider_name\n            provider_logo\n            expires\n            price\n            home_coverage\n            contents_coverage\n            disclaimer\n          }}\n        }}\n        noise {{\n          score\n        }}\n      }}\n      location {{\n        address {{\n          city\n          coordinate {{\n            lat\n            lon\n          }}\n          country\n          line\n          postal_code\n          state\n          state_code\n          street_direction\n          street_name\n          street_number\n          street_post_direction\n          street_suffix\n          unit\n          validation_code\n        }}\n        county {{\n          fips_code\n          name\n          state_code\n        }}\n        neighborhoods {{\n          city\n          id\n          level\n          name\n          state_code\n          slug_id\n        }}\n        search_areas {{\n          city\n          state_code\n        }}\n      }}\n      nearby_schools {{\n        schools {{\n          coordinate {{\n            lat\n            lon\n          }}\n          distance_in_miles\n          district {{\n            id\n            name\n          }}\n          education_levels\n          funding_type\n          grades\n          greatschools_id\n          id\n          name\n          nces_code\n          parent_rating\n          rating\n          review_count\n          slug_id\n          student_count\n        }}\n      }}\n      photo_count\n      photos {{\n        title\n        description\n        href\n        type\n      }}\n      primary_photo {{\n        href\n      }}\n      property_history {{\n        date\n        event_name\n        price\n        price_sqft\n        source_listing_id\n        source_name\n        listing @include_if(field: "status", operator: in, value: "sold,off_market,other") {{\n          list_price\n          last_status_change_date\n          last_update_date\n          status\n          list_date\n          listing_id\n          suppression_flags\n          photos {{\n            href\n          }}\n          description {{\n            text\n          }}\n          advertisers {{\n            fulfillment_id\n            nrds_id\n            name\n            email\n            href\n            slogan\n            office {{\n              fulfillment_id\n              name\n              email\n              href\n              slogan\n              out_of_community\n              application_url\n              mls_set\n            }}\n            broker {{\n              fulfillment_id\n              name\n              accent_color\n              logo\n            }}\n            type\n            mls_set\n          }}\n          buyers {{\n            fulfillment_id\n            nrds_id\n            name\n            email\n            href\n            slogan\n            type\n            mls_set\n            address {{\n              line\n              city\n              postal_code\n              state_code\n              state\n              country\n              coordinate {{\n                lat\n                lon\n              }}\n            }}\n            office {{\n              fulfillment_id\n              name\n              email\n              href\n              slogan\n              hours\n              out_of_community\n              application_url\n              mls_set\n              address {{\n                line\n                city\n                postal_code\n                state_code\n                state\n                country\n              }}\n              phones {{\n                number\n                type\n                primary\n                trackable\n                ext\n              }}\n              county {{\n                name\n              }}\n            }}\n            phones {{\n              number\n              type\n              primary\n              trackable\n              ext\n            }}\n            broker {{\n              fulfillment_id\n              name\n              accent_color\n              logo\n            }}\n          }}\n          source {{\n            id\n            agents {{\n              agent_id\n              agent_name\n              office_id\n              office_name\n              office_phone\n              type\n            }}\n          }}\n        }}\n      }}\n      property_id\n      provider_url {{\n        href\n        level\n        type\n      }}\n      source {{\n        agents {{\n          agent_id\n          agent_name\n          id\n          office_id\n          office_name\n          office_phone\n          type\n        }}\n        disclaimer {{\n          href\n          logo {{\n            href\n            height\n            width\n          }}\n          text\n        }}\n        id\n        plan_id\n        listing_id\n        name\n        raw {{\n          status\n          style\n          tax_amount\n        }}\n        type\n        community_id\n      }}\n      status\n      suppression_flags\n      tags\n      tax_history {{\n        assessment {{\n          building\n          land\n          total\n        }}\n        market {{\n          building\n          land\n          total\n        }}\n        tax\n        year\n      }}\n    }}\n  }}'

            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=self.base_url,
                method="POST",
                dont_filter=True,
                headers=self.headers,
                body=json.dumps(self.json_data),
                callback=self.parse_details,
            )

    def parse_details(self, response):
        item = {}
        prop_detail = response.json()
        prop_tax = prop_detail["data"]["home"]["tax_history"]
        try:
            tax_building_assessment = [
                tab["assessment"]["building"] for tab in prop_tax
            ]

            for idx, tab in enumerate(tax_building_assessment):
                item[f"property_history_tax_building_assessment_{idx}"] = tab
                yield item[f"property_history_tax_building_assessment_{idx}"]

            tax_landing_assessment = [tal["assessment"]["land"] for tal in prop_tax]

            for idx, tla in enumerate(tax_landing_assessment):
                item[f"property_history_tax_landing_assessment_{idx}"] = tla
                yield item[f"property_history_tax_landing_assessment_{idx}"]

            tax_total_assessment = [tat["assessment"]["total"] for tat in prop_tax]

            for idx, tta in enumerate(tax_total_assessment):
                item[f"property_history_tax_total_assessment_{idx}"] = tta
                yield item[f"property_history_tax_total_assessment_{idx}"]

            tax_building_market = [tmb["market"]["building"] for tmb in prop_tax]

            for idx, tbm in enumerate(tax_building_market):
                item[f"property_history_tax_building_market_{idx}"] = tbm
                yield item[f"property_history_tax_building_market__{idx}"]

            tax_land_market = [tml["market"]["land"] for tml in prop_tax]

            for idx, tlm in enumerate(tax_land_market):
                item[f"property_history_tax_land_market_{idx}"] = tlm
                yield item[f"property_history_tax_land_market_{idx}"]

            tax_total_market = [tmt["market"]["total"] for tmt in prop_tax]

            for idx, ttm in enumerate(tax_total_market):
                item[f"property_history_tax_total_market_{idx}"] = ttm
                yield item[f"property_history_tax_total_market_{idx}"]

            tax = [tx["tax"] for tx in prop_tax]

            for idx, tx in enumerate(tax):
                item[f"property_history_tax_{idx}"] = tx
                yield item[f"property_history_tax_{idx}"]

            tax_year = [txy["year"] for txy in prop_tax]

            for idx, txy in enumerate(tax_year):
                item[f"property_history_tax_year_{idx}"] = txy
                yield item[f"property_history_tax_year_{idx}"]
        except:
            pass

        yield item


# main driver
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # run scrapper
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(RealtorScraper)
    process.start()
```

Logs:

```
2022-04-02 21:14:47 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST https://www.realtor.com/api/v1/hulk?client_id=rdc-x&schema=vesta> (referer: None)
2022-04-02 21:14:47 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST https://www.realtor.com/api/v1/hulk?client_id=rdc-x&schema=vesta> (referer: None)
2022-04-02 21:14:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.realtor.com/api/v1/hulk?client_id=rdc-x&schema=vesta>
{'property_history_tax_building_assessment_0': 223965, 'property_history_tax_building_assessment_1': 179165, 'property_history_tax_building_assessment_2': 179165, 'property_history_tax_building_assessment_3': 179165, 'property_history_tax_building_assessment_4': 179690, 'property_history_tax_building_assessment_5': 179690, 'property_history_tax_building_assessment_6': 179690, 'property_history_tax_building_assessment_7': 179690, 'property_history_tax_building_assessment_8': 179690, 'property_history_tax_building_assessment_9': 179690, 'property_history_tax_landing_assessment_0': 241185, 'property_history_tax_landing_assessment_1': 192955, 'property_history_tax_landing_assessment_2': 192955, 'property_history_tax_landing_assessment_3': 192955, 'property_history_tax_landing_assessment_4': 192955, 'property_history_tax_landing_assessment_5': 192955, 'property_history_tax_landing_assessment_6': 192955, 'property_history_tax_landing_assessment_7': 192955, 'property_history_tax_landing_assessment_8': 192955, 'property_history_tax_landing_assessment_9': 192955, 'property_history_tax_total_assessment_0': 465150, 'property_history_tax_total_assessment_1': 372120, 'property_history_tax_total_assessment_2': 372120, 'property_history_tax_total_assessment_3': 372120, 'property_history_tax_total_assessment_4': 372645, 'property_history_tax_total_assessment_5': 372645, 'property_history_tax_total_assessment_6': 372645, 'property_history_tax_total_assessment_7': 372645, 'property_history_tax_total_assessment_8': 372645, 'property_history_tax_total_assessment_9': 372645, 'property_history_tax_building_market_0': 639900, 'property_history_tax_building_market_1': 511900, 'property_history_tax_building_market_2': 511900, 'property_history_tax_building_market_3': 511900, 'property_history_tax_building_market_4': 513400, 'property_history_tax_building_market_5': 513400, 'property_history_tax_building_market_6': 513400, 'property_history_tax_building_market_7': 513400, 'property_history_tax_building_market_8': 513400, 'property_history_tax_building_market_9': 513400, 'property_history_tax_land_market_0': 689100, 'property_history_tax_land_market_1': 551300, 'property_history_tax_land_market_2': 551300, 'property_history_tax_land_market_3': 551300, 'property_history_tax_land_market_4': 551300, 'property_history_tax_land_market_5': 551300, 'property_history_tax_land_market_6': 551300, 'property_history_tax_land_market_7': 551300, 'property_history_tax_land_market_8': 551300, 'property_history_tax_land_market_9': 551300, 'property_history_tax_total_market_0': 1329000, 'property_history_tax_total_market_1': 1063200, 'property_history_tax_total_market_2': 1063200, 'property_history_tax_total_market_3': 1063200, 'property_history_tax_total_market_4': 1064700, 'property_history_tax_total_market_5': 1064700, 'property_history_tax_total_market_6': 1064700, 'property_history_tax_total_market_7': 1064700, 'property_history_tax_total_market_8': 1064700, 'property_history_tax_total_market_9': 1064700, 'property_history_tax_0': 41773, 'property_history_tax_1': 37412, 'property_history_tax_2': 37398, 'property_history_tax_3': 35448, 'property_history_tax_4': 37572, 'property_history_tax_5': 37540, 'property_history_tax_6': 37516, 'property_history_tax_7': 37359, 'property_history_tax_8': 36596, 'property_history_tax_9': 33682, 'property_history_tax_year_0': 2020, 'property_history_tax_year_1': 2019, 'property_history_tax_year_2': 2019, 'property_history_tax_year_3': 2017, 'property_history_tax_year_4': 2016, 'property_history_tax_year_5': 2015, 'property_history_tax_year_6': 2014, 'property_history_tax_year_7': 2013, 'property_history_tax_year_8': 2012, 'property_history_tax_year_9': 2011}
2022-04-02 21:14:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.realtor.com/api/v1/hulk?client_id=rdc-x&schema=vesta>
{}
2022-04-02 21:14:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.realtor.com/api/v1/hulk?client_id=rdc-x&schema=vesta>
{'property_history_tax_building_assessment_0': None, 'property_history_tax_building_assessment_1': None, 'property_history_tax_building_assessment_2': None, 'property_history_tax_building_assessment_3': None, 'property_history_tax_building_assessment_4': None, 'property_history_tax_building_assessment_5': None, 'property_history_tax_building_assessment_6': None, 'property_history_tax_building_assessment_7': None, 'property_history_tax_building_assessment_8': None, 'property_history_tax_building_assessment_9': None, 'property_history_tax_landing_assessment_0': 225750, 'property_history_tax_landing_assessment_1': 180600, 'property_history_tax_landing_assessment_2': 180600, 'property_history_tax_landing_assessment_3': 180600, 'property_history_tax_landing_assessment_4': 180600, 'property_history_tax_landing_assessment_5': 180600, 'property_history_tax_landing_assessment_6': 180600, 'property_history_tax_landing_assessment_7': 180600, 'property_history_tax_landing_assessment_8': 180600, 'property_history_tax_landing_assessment_9': 180600, 'property_history_tax_total_assessment_0': 225750, 'property_history_tax_total_assessment_1': 180600, 'property_history_tax_total_assessment_2': 180600, 'property_history_tax_total_assessment_3': 180600, 'property_history_tax_total_assessment_4': 180600, 'property_history_tax_total_assessment_5': 180600, 'property_history_tax_total_assessment_6': 180600, 'property_history_tax_total_assessment_7': 180600, 'property_history_tax_total_assessment_8': 180600, 'property_history_tax_total_assessment_9': 180600, 'property_history_tax_building_market_0': None, 'property_history_tax_building_market_1': None, 'property_history_tax_building_market_2': None, 'property_history_tax_building_market_3': None, 'property_history_tax_building_market_4': None, 'property_history_tax_building_market_5': None, 'property_history_tax_building_market_6': None, 'property_history_tax_building_market_7': None, 'property_history_tax_building_market_8': None, 'property_history_tax_building_market_9': None, 'property_history_tax_land_market_0': 645000, 'property_history_tax_land_market_1': 516000, 'property_history_tax_land_market_2': 516000, 'property_history_tax_land_market_3': 516000, 'property_history_tax_land_market_4': 516000, 'property_history_tax_land_market_5': 516000, 'property_history_tax_land_market_6': 516000, 'property_history_tax_land_market_7': 516000, 'property_history_tax_land_market_8': 516000, 'property_history_tax_land_market_9': 516000, 'property_history_tax_total_market_0': 645000, 'property_history_tax_total_market_1': 516000, 'property_history_tax_total_market_2': 516000, 'property_history_tax_total_market_3': 516000, 'property_history_tax_total_market_4': 516000, 'property_history_tax_total_market_5': 516000, 'property_history_tax_total_market_6': 516000, 'property_history_tax_total_market_7': 516000, 'property_history_tax_total_market_8': 516000, 'property_history_tax_total_market_9': 516000, 'property_history_tax_0': 20273, 'property_history_tax_1': 18157, 'property_history_tax_2': 18150, 'property_history_tax_3': 17203, 'property_history_tax_4': 18209, 'property_history_tax_5': 18193, 'property_history_tax_6': 18181, 'property_history_tax_7': 18106, 'property_history_tax_8': 17736, 'property_history_tax_9': 16323, 'property_history_tax_year_0': 2020, 'property_history_tax_year_1': 2019, 'property_history_tax_year_2': 2019, 'property_history_tax_year_3': 2017, 'property_history_tax_year_4': 2016, 'property_history_tax_year_5': 2015, 'property_history_tax_year_6': 2014, 'property_history_tax_year_7': 2013, 'property_history_tax_year_8': 2012, 'property_history_tax_year_9': 2011}
```

I tried to put that whole block of code into try/except but no success at getting data for example it runs without error but gives empty csv. Can anyone please look at it and see what am I doing wrong or how to achieve my desired result.

Comment: Can you not just do `prop_tax = prop_detail["data"]["home"]["tax_history"] or []` ?

Comment: still it would be none I tried this still the same empty csv.

Comment: Well.. that bare `except` could well be masking errors... you're better off removing your try/except and see if anything pops up. Also  - you don't say how you're running the spider - you are passing it something like: `-o output.csv` to actually have it output something?

Comment: without try/except it works with proper csv file but with errors I showed above and not scraping whole list like there is 400+ links and it gives me 309 scrape count. I am declaring csv output in custom settings dictionary.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/, and try to isolate the problem yourself first.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just eliminate the None values in the list comprehension?

```
tax_building_assessment = [
   tab["assessment"]["building"] for tab in prop_tax if tab is not None
        ]
```